# Update Data with Form and pre values from Database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to create a Form where the user can edit the existing data, but all the values should be already in the Formfields.
I know how to do it in simple HTML with

```
<input type="text" name="myValue" value="Existing Value">
```

But I cant find out how to do it in Symfony with Doctrine.

I already created the Form for Insert like this.

```
class VideoContentUpdateType extends AbstractType     
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')... and so on.
```

To get the id i use a controller with normal slug, but i don't know where to pass it.

```
* @Route("/giantcontent/video/edit/{slug})
 */
public function editVideoForm($slug)
{

    $em =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $video= $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Video");
```

But I'm really clueless how to go on.
I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Edit1:
I tried to read the documentation from symfony:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html
But I'm not getting smarter, thanks for your afford.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know i should not post link to information and try to explain it here. But your question is very wide, and it will consist a lot of code which is already written in official symfony documentation. Please check here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html

And more about forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

And what to do with ID (from the link above):

```
$video = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Video')->find($id);

if (!$video) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('No ;video found for id '.$id);
}

$editForm = $this->createForm($video);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  allready created a lot of forms with symfony,  that was the easy part,  I'll allready red the crud part,   but i didn't get smarter probably I'm to tired.  i should rest for today and read it again tomorrow.

Comment: symfony documentation is really good, and it contains a lot of answers to basic questions. just double check it, you will find all info and examples

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution with the help of twig, its probably not the best and not perfect but it's easy and fast to implement.

```
{{ form_widget(form.title,{'value':videos.title }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.link,{'value':videos.link }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.album,{'value':videos.album }) }}
```